# VueJS Vee-Validate Validation Not Happening On Input

Tags: javascript, validation, vuejs2

I have a very basic VueJS form, wherein I am validating the input.

The form validation happens on initial call to the validate form method, and the appropriate validation messages are displayed on each input.

What I am puzzled about is that on the [vee-validate example for the forms](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/examples#validate-form), clicking on the submit button invokes the validation, and then displays the error message for each form input. Once you enter a value on the input (say on the name field), you can clearly see that the validation error and message for that field is removed.

I am providing a sample [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/gipozahade/edit?html,js,output) illustrating the issue I am having.

On the output panel, click on the Validate Form button, and you can see that the validation is working. But once you enter some text on the input field (i.e. First Name), the validation does not work anymore, unless you explicitly click again on the Validate Form button. This does not seem to be the same behavior on the Vee-Validate form.

Am I overlooking or missing something? Appreciate any input on what may be causing the issue as I am quite new with VueJS.

Thanks.

Codes as from JSBin:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app" class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" @submit.prevent="validateBeforeSubmit">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-sm-4" for="firstName">First Name:</label>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-8" v-bind:class="{ 'has-error' : errors.has('FirstName') }">
          <input name="FirstName" v-model="firstName" v-validate:firstName.initial="'required|alpha|min:3'" class="form-control" type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="" v-bind:class="{ 'input': true, 'has-error': errors.has('FirstName') }" >
          <span v-show="errors.has('FirstName')" class="help-block error text-danger">{{ errors.first('FirstName') }}</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-sm-4" for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-8" v-bind:class="{ 'has-error' : errors.has('LastName') }">
          <input name="LastName" v-model="lastName" v-validate:lastName.initial="'required|alpha|min:3'" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="" v-bind:class="{ 'input': true, 'has-error': errors.has('lastName') }" >
          <span v-show="errors.has('LastName')" class="help-block error text-danger">{{ errors.first('LastName') }}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

    <a class="btn btn-success btn-md " v-on:click="validateBeforeSubmit">Validate Form</a>
    <hr />
    <pre>{{ errors }}</pre>
    <pre>{{ fields }}</pre>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vee-validate/2.0.0-beta.21/vee-validate.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
Vue.use(VeeValidate);

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    firstName: null,
    lastName: null
  },

  methods:{
    validateBeforeSubmit: function(){
      function onOk(){
        alert('Form is OK');
      }

      function notOk(){
        alert('Form Not OK');
      }

      this.$validator.validateAll().then(onOk, notOk);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is in the documentation, you have to make following changes:

1. Only put `v-validate="'required|alpha|min:3'"`
2. You can add `data-vv-delay="100"` to get errors after 100ms or whatever time you deem fine.

see HTML below :

```
<input name="FirstName" v-model="firstName"  data-vv-delay="100" v-validate="'required|alpha|min:3'" class="form-control" type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="" v-bind:class="{ 'input': true, 'has-error': errors.has('FirstName') }" >
```

See working [bin](http://jsbin.com/qezibosuxe/edit?html,console,output).

Comment: I will accept this as an answer, but I just want to gain an understanding as to why on the example on the site for the Forms Validation, the attributes were specified as:  v-validate:name.initial="'required|alpha'"? I clearly followed the same on my form, and for reason I want to also know, it is breaking the validation.

Comment: There's just another issue on the solution you provided. Once your cursor is in the input field, and you tab away or set focus to another control, the validation occurs outright. Seems removing the v-validate:FIELDNAME.initial removes the behavior to only validate on the click of button.

Comment: @Angelo I am also referring to [documentation](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/#basic-example) only.